# Matlab character to string convertion problem. What function to use?

Tags: string, matlab, char, string-formatting, strcat

```
x = 1234     56789     7654
```

x(1) is 1, x(2) is 2 and so on... there are 5 spaces in between..
size(x) = 1 23 
One row with 23 columns
I've tried using num2str, strcat but I cannot club the numbers. 
y = num2str(x), y = strcat(x)

I want it to be.. x(1) = 1234, x(2) = 56789, x(3) = 7654

What function should I use to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is to use `sscanf`:

```
x =' 1234     56789     7654'

sscanf(x, '%d')

ans =

    1234
   56789
    7654
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm so dumb! I didn know this!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of performing what you want. One of them is strtok.

```
x = '1234     56789     7654';
[fst rest] = strtok(x,' ');
```

Comment: This will output strings not numbers and it only splits once.

Answer (score 0):

[STR2NUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2num.html) works well for this task:

```
>> x = '1234     56789     7654';
>> x = str2num(x)'

x =

        1234
       56789
        7654
```

Comment: Take care when using STR2NUM because it is based on EVAL.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another answer to the mix...

```
y = textscan(x, '%d     %d     %d')
```

Comment: more simply as: `y = textscan(x,'%d');`. Also you should probably add `y = y{1};`

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a cell array of strings then follows it up with an application of sscanf.

```
b = regexp(x,'\d+','match');
y = cellfun(@(a) (sscanf(a,'%d')),b);
```